# Find the timestamp of a unique ticket number

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table that looks like this:

```
**ActivityNumber -- TimeStamp        -- PreviousActivityNumber -- Team**
1234-4         -- 01/01/2017 14:12 -- 1234-3                   -- Team A
```

There are 400,000 rows.
The ActivityNumber is a unique ticket number with the activity count attached.  There are 4 teams.
Each activitynumber is in the table.

I need to calculate the average time taken between updates for each team, for each month (to see how each team is improving over time).

I produced a query which counts the number of activities per team per month - so I'm part way there.

I'm unable to find the timestamp for the previousActivityNumber so I can subtract it from the current Activity number.  If I could get this, I could run an average on it.

Comment: Pls post sample input/output and what have u tried...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually:

```
select a1.Team,
       a1.ActivityNumber, 
       a1.TimeStamp, 
       a2.Timestamp as PrevTime, 
       datediff('n',a1.Timestamp, a2.timestamp) as WorkMinutes
from MyTable a1
left join MyTable a2
on ((a1.Team = a2.Team)
and (a1.PreviousActivityNumber = a2.ActivityNumber )
```

Comment: This answer is what you are looking for.  Specifically,the concept of a self join.  This will bring in your previous time stamp easily, and allow for easy calculation as well!

Comment: Perfect. The join was what I was missing. All sorted now. Really appreciate the help.